# Unable To Install Symfony Windows 7

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install `Symfony`, but unable to find how can we start with `symfony` with `Xampp`. I have already tried on google but there is no proper solution for installation and configuration of `Symfony`.

As I want to edit a project which is already developed using `symfony` CMS.

Comment: Why google? Symfony has a very good documenation, even for installing: https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup.html

Comment: You say that you just want to edit a project, then you don't need to install symfony, you have it in your current project

Answer (score 0):

Symfony is not a CMS.

If you need to run a symfony app locally, all you have to do is to copy all files into a project subdirectory inside your Xampp (for example htdocs/symfony).

I assume existing project will have a database, so be sure to import your database locally or use external database. You need to tweak your symfony config file: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to install Symfony, but unable to find how can we start with >symfony with Xampp. I have already tried on google but there is no proper >solution for installation and configuration of Symfony.
>   As I want to edit a project which is already developed using symfony CMS.

Hi, for begin Symfony is not a CMS but a framework ^^, it's a little bit (alot) different.

For install Symfony WHY use google O_o ----> http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

After, why Xampp ? for windows use Wamp who do the local server it's more performing :/

And if you want you don't have necessary to install symfony if it's an existing project -> just clone it (if he is on github) ... and just open the complete folder with your IDE or text editor.
You can modify the file without problems, (just you can have a prob for use command php bin/console.

Good luck i hope it's answering all you questions :)